# Calling function every 3 sec

Tags: c, timer, sdl

I have a problem with timer in C. I have to call a function every 3 sec (for e.g. To put down Hello world! every 3 sec). It must not wait on calling function. I'm doing a game, so function will be used to make random coordinates, but I must be able to move my player around.

Any hints?

Comment: A second thread that blocks for three seconds is needed.

Comment: Read about; `sigaction()`, `alarm()` and `write()`.

Comment: Have you tried using the sleep function

Comment: No i hav not tried sleep function. I ll look about it.

Comment: Sleep function is not working. I stop whol program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a Linux enviornment, you could consider something like this:

```
void hello_word_func(int signum)
{
    printf ("Hello World!\n");
    signal (SIGALRM, hello_word_func);
    alarm (3);
}

signal (SIGALRM, hello_word_func);
alarm (3);
```

Another option, which will eat more of your CPU's resources (busy-wait) is to spawn a new thread, and issue a loop of outputting "Hello World" and sleeping for 3 seconds.

Comment: `sleep` from `<unistd.h>` does not busy wait.

Comment: You're right. My mistake.

Comment: `printf()` (along with lots of other functions) is not async signal safe. Use `write(fileno(stdout), ...)`  to print to `stdout` instead.